# Is rails 4 supporting active_scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activescaffold

rails 4 + ruby 2.0

Is rails 4 is supporting active_scaffold ?

**by source** : https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold

Overview

"ActiveScaffold provides a quick and powerful user interfaces for CRUD (create, read, update, delete) operations for Rails applications. It offers additonal features including searching, pagination & layout control. **Rails 3.2 and 4** are supported."

When i am trying with a brand new rails project.

1) gem 'active_scaffold'

2) bundle install

3) bundle exec rake db:create

## Error

This version of ActiveScaffold requires Rails 3.1 or higher.  Please use an earlier version.

/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/gems/active_scaffold-3.2.20/xyz/active_scaffold.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`require'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in`each'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in`each'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in`require'
/home/xyz/RoRProjects/active_scaff/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/RoRProjects/active_scaff/Rakefile:4:in`require'
/home/xyz/RoRProjects/active_scaff/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
/home/xyz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is Yes! rails 4 is supporting active_scaffold.

1) gem 'active_scaffold', github: 'activescaffold/active_scaffold'

2) bundle install

3) bundle exec rake db:create

4) rails g active_scaffold User name:string

5) bundle exec rake db:migrate

Done!